# Python: Converting Dictionary With Key Value Pairs That Contain A List of Values into A List of Tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to take a dictionary with key value pairs in which the values are a list and turn them into a list of tuples.

I have a the following dictionary:

```
d={'a': [33, 21, 4, 32], 'b': [6, 100, 8, 14]}
```

Desired output:

```
[(33, 6), (21, 100), (4, 8), (32, 14)]
```

Below is the code I tried but it does not get me there.

```
d={'a': [33, 21, 4, 32], 'b': [6, 100, 8, 14]}
  
# Converting into list of tuple 
list = [(key, value) for key, value in d.items()] 
  
# Printing list of tuple 
print(list)
```

The code outputs a list value of :

```
[('a', [33, 21, 4, 32]), ('b', [6, 100, 8, 14])]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the dict values together:

```
>>> d = {'a': [33, 21, 4, 32], 'b': [6, 100, 8, 14]}
>>> list(zip(*d.values()))
[(33, 6), (21, 100), (4, 8), (32, 14)]
```

If you only want to get a specific range of values efficiently you could use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) before consuming it with list.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> list(islice(zip(*d.values()), 2))
[(33, 6), (21, 100)]
```

Comment: oh wow!  thank you.  can you explain to me what zip and * are doing?

Comment: I linked the docs on it in my answer. It basically iterates over multiple iterables returning a tuple of each element for every element in each iterable. Hope that lamens it enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the faster and more concise solution by *Jab*.
But if you have a bigger input dictionary, but need to extract only a few values, you can also use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
like so:

```
lst = [(d['a'][i], d['b'][i]) for i in range(len(d['a']))]
```

Comment: very nifty!  I tried a different version of your code but it doesn't work (returns [(32, 14)].  Can you enlighten me on why it's wrong please?  

for i in range(0, len(d['a'])):
  list = [(d['a'][i], d['b'][i])]

Comment: Also a great solution. Although I believe using `itertools.islice` on the `zip` would be more efficient (unless you're start index is not 0 maybe) as `zip` returns an iterable not a list in py3. See my edit in my answer

Comment: @PineNuts0 You need to start with an empty list outside the loop, and **append** to it in the loop. In you snippet, you **assign** (not append) to the list, which overwrites the previous contents. That's why you end up with a list with just a single element: the last tuple from the input.